# How to set Word2007 to reject US spellings for Canadian dictionary

Tags: microsoft-word-2007

I've got MSWord2007 set to use a Canadian dictionary but it's still accepting American spelling for words (i.e. 'color' instead of 'colour'). I would like it to reject/highlight any spelling that does not conform to Canadian dictionaries, but Word 2007 is very alien to me. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Never mind... Google teaches me things! I found that I had both US and Canadian dictionaries enabled.

For reference, go to the Office Tools folder from Windows' start menu and select 'Microsoft Office Language Settings', you can add/remove dictionaries there.

Reference link: http://www.lizjamieson.co.uk/2007/12/03/how-to-set-the-default-language-dictionary-on-microsoft-word-2007/